# Gmail Add-on before sending the email do modification to the signature

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I'm new with `Google Script`, but finally I created an add-on to modify the current signature, so gmail won't trim the signatures when someone receive it.

The idea is, this add-on will be triggered when I send an email to someone, so basically this add-on will be always on. but I don't know how to trigger it when I'm sending an email, because in apps script, the trigger function only for these options:
[image]

here is my code so far

```
function setSignature() {
  var date = new Date();
  var timestamp = date.getTime();

  var aliases = [];

  Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs.forEach(function(e) {
    if (e.isPrimary === true) {
      aliases.push({
        sendAsEmail: e.sendAsEmail,
        replyToAddress: e.replyToAddress,
        displayName: e.displayName,
        treatAsAlias: e.treatAsAlias,
        signature: e.signature +"<div style='color: #fff;'>"+ timestamp +"</div>"
      });
    }
  });

  Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.patch(aliases, "me", aliases[0]["sendAsEmail"]);
}
```

and here is the `appsscript` file

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Hong_Kong",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Gmail",
      "serviceId": "gmail",
      "version": "v1"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing"]
}
```

and when I tried to use the add-on, it's failed. Here is the step by step what I'm doing:

I get the add-on ID from `Publish > Deploy from Manifest`
[image]

and then I enable the developer mode and add the ID from before
[image]

But why it's said invalid add-on?
[image]

Comment: Did you ensure your ID is correct and that your account has permission to access the add-on?

Comment: yes it's already correct and I have the permission access granted for the add-on @noogui

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do won't be possible. Add-Ons do not know what is happening outside of them. A **Gmail add-on** cannot detect that you have sent an email through the Gmail UI you would need to build **Gmail Browser Extension** to be able to do what you are looking for.

We have been trying to do something similar without any luck.

Comment: I see, then is it possible to change the signature every 1 minutes? I think it's kinda more possible?